# Are flash loan attacks possible in layer 2 async blockchain?

Tags: eth-2.0, sharding

Flash loans attack has become a new normal every week. But I have read that it won't be possible in async sharding, but couldn't find enough information about it online. Is the information correct, if yes, why it's not possible in sharded blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

A flash-loan means that you must return the loan within the same transaction in which you took it.

So the answer to your question is no, **by definition**.